# How to set root pasword in mysql 8 in ubuntu

Tags: mysql

Installed MySQL 8 on Ubuntu; but I didn't get the option of setting the root password. So now when I am trying to login with the command "mysql -u root -p" its saying "Access denied for 'root'@'localhost'. How to set the root password now? Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are all the steps to reset the root password for MySQL:

Run the below command on your OS Command line:

```
systemctl stop mysqld
systemctl set-environment MYSQLD_OPTS="--skip-grant-tables"
systemctl start mysqld
```

Now, Login with "root", it will not ask for the password.

```
mysql -u root
```

Within "mysql", update the password for root user as below update statement.

```
alter user 'root'@'localhost' identified by 'your_new_password';
```

Now, exit the "mysql" and stop the mysql service as:

```
systemctl stop mysqld
```

Run the below command on your OS Command line:

```
systemctl unset-environment MYSQLD_OPTS
systemctl start mysqld
```

Now, try to connect mysql using root password

```
mysql -u root -p
```

All the best!!!

Comment: Doesn't work at all for me. Tells mysqld is not installed

Comment: Anyway have logged into the myql server without root password and its showing the "mysql>" prompt. But when I enter "alter user 'root'@'localhost' identified by 'your_new_password';" command its showing "ERROR 1449 (HY000): The user specified as a definer ('mysql.infoschema'@'localhost') does not exist". 
what to do now? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @SandipNath Try with *mysql* instead of *mysqld*.

Comment: for ubuntu 22.04LTS the service must be `mysql.service`

Comment: Furyhermore I think it needs `flush privileges;` upon assword change otherwise it wont be appplied.